# Really need g77 on Ubuntu 12.04, can't install

Tags: fortran

I am running an extensive code that I requires g77 to compile. (yes I could probably debug for gfortran but it took me months just to get it working so I really really don't want to). I have tried [http://astrokode.wordpress.com/2012/10/31/installing-g77-compiler](http://astrokode.wordpress.com/2012/10/31/installing-g77-compiler-in-ubuntu-10-04-11-10-12-04/)

but I get this error when I try to install:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package g77 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'g77' has no installation candidate
```

I have seen on forums that people are installing the g77 for Ubuntu 8.04, but I am fairly new to Ubuntu and unclear of exactly how to do this.

Comment: Could you tell use the name of this program? I think I found a solution without the need of old libraries.

Comment: g77 is considered obsolete and no longer maintained by the gcc developers. I'm afraid you'd have to compile an ancient release of gcc (<4.0) from source to get g77. This should not be much of an issue, yet it'd take some time. Also, of course, I'd not install an old gcc system wide, but in a subfolder of your /home directory.     
Another thing: f2c seems to be more compatible with g77 than gfortran. You might be lucky and your program might compile with f2c.

Comment: Can you explain how to compile an old version of gcc and install in a subfolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been tested on 12.04, and 13.04.  I beleive its version 3.4.  To install, first you need to download either the [32bit](http://ubuntuone.com/1Y8lxLb37rzEfuXcBeFCNk), or [64bit](http://ubuntuone.com/5BYMLVwfbtcCyooiswgRBn) g77.  Once downloaded, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the location where the files where downloaded (probably the downloads folder), and run the command(s) below:

For 32bit

```
tar -xzvf g77_x86_debian_and_ubuntu.tar.gz
cd  g77_x86_debian_and_ubuntu
chmod +x ./install.sh
./install.sh
```

For 64bit

```
tar -xzvf g77_x64_debian_and_ubuntu.tar.gz
cd  g77_x64_debian_and_ubuntu
chmod +x ./install.sh
./install.sh
```

---

[image]

<sup>Source:[sanjeev kumar](https://plus.google.com/102974216418126052144?prsrc=2)</sup>

Comment: Glad that it worked for you :)

Comment: Is it apparently not possible to install both the 32 and 64 bit versions using these packages. Is there a way to to do that?