# How do I install gfortran?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am trying to install `gfortran` in my computer with Ubuntu 12.04 by using these commands,

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install gfortran
```

but I found the program saying "`unable to locate package gfortran`".
Then on a Ubuntu page I found some question regarding the same problem and I went through the solution from them but again I couldn't install the `gfortran` package.

Can anybody tell me how to install it?

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/346278/really-need-g77-on-ubuntu-12-04-cant-install/346288#346288).

Comment: Do you get any error while running `apt-get update`? Can you provide the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Answer (score 31):

Using `sudo apt-get install gfortran` should install the latest version of gfortran available for your system. [Madison](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/madison.cgi?package=gfortran&a=&c=&s=) has a list of all versions available for all supported versions.

Comment: I couldn't get the commands you gave to work, but since you wrote this gfortran4.8 has come out. The command that worked for me was just "sudo apt-get install gfortran". But that was after I added gcc and other things.

Comment: How to install 4.8?

Comment: @ChillarAnand just install gfortran package.