# How to install gfortran 5 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa, synaptic

I want to install gfortran 5. As per [how do I install gfortran](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358907/how-do-i-install-gfortran), I tried
`sudo apt-get install gfortran` but it installs 4.8.4 gfortran compiler. I searched and found [this](https://scivision.co/installing-gfortran-4-9-on-ubuntu-14-04/).

When I wrote,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

it gives error

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

I am not expert in linux or ubuntu so just searched ways on internet, but no luck so far. On [this webpage](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/amd64/gfortran-5), it prompts a download link, but I have no clue how to install that package.

**Update:**
As per above link of ubuntu package gfortran-5, I installed synaptic package, but it doesn't find gfortran-5.

Does anyone know workarounds?

Comment: Have you tried to add the PPA manually?

Answer (score 1):

[gfortran-5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gfortran-5) is not currently available for Ubuntu 14.04 "Trusty". There are however packages available for 16.04 "Xenial" and later. If you must have Version 5 and can't get by with [version 4.8](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gfortran-4.8) which is the latest currently available in the repositories for Trusty, You have some options.

A) Upgrade your installation to 16.04 LTS which will be supported for 2 years longer than your current installation.

B) Attempt to compile from [source](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#FromSource)

Personally I would consider approach A to have the best chance of success.

Sources:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gfortran&searchon=names

https://launchpad.net/+search?field.text=gfortran-5

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#FromSource